# conditional expectation with random sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $N$ is a random natural number, and $X_1,\ldots,$ is a sequence of not necessarily identically distributed random variables, the [generalized Wald identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#General_version) states that $$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^NE(X_i)\right).$$ Is there an analogous identity for $$E\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right)?$$

Comment: Not sure it is true in general, since section here ( "A proof using the optional stopping theorem", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#A_proof_using_the_optional_stopping_theorem),  ) does not seem to give back immediately/naively a martingale, but of course this is just a comment

Answer (score 2):

If $X_i$ and $N$ are independent, it follows analogously,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i\right) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i\bigg|N\right)\right)\\ &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\bigg|N\right)\right)\\ &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote, maybe because the hypothesis of independence is not in Wald's general statement ? ( personally I upvoted )

Comment: I'm not the downvoter either but I do wonder about the second equality. How do you pull the summation out of the conditional expectation?

Comment: TomChen can can answer better. In the meanwhile, if you condition on N (like in the internal expectation), then N is a constant. The rest follows by linearity.